# how do you map path in razor for .net core 2.0 mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to convert a layout page to .net core 2.0.  unfortunately in razor Server.MapPath is no longer available.

I am trying to find the equivalent in a .cshtml page for

```
<div style="height: 0px; width: 0px; position: absolute; visibility: hidden;">
        @Html.Raw(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(Server.MapPath("~/Content/images/svg-defs.svg")))
    </div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In ASP.NET Core, you can use the `IHostingEnvironment` service to gain access to certain paths of the webapp.

There are two interesting properties on this object:

- `ContentRootPath`: the path to the applications base path (where you would usually find appsettings.json, Program.cs, etc
- `WebRootPath`: the path to the /wwwroot directory, which is what you are looking for.

To get access to the `IHostingEnvironment` service, simply inject it in the constructor of your controller and hold on it with a field.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IHostingEnvironment _env;

    public HomeController(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        _env = env;   
    }
}
```

Now, in an action method of this Controller, you can now construct the physical path to a file using `System.IO.Path.Combine` and the `WebRootPath` property.

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.FilePath = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, @"Content\images\svg-defs.svg");
    return View();
}
```

In this example I added the resulting path to the `ViewBag` to easily display it in the Index view:

```
<h2>Index View</h2>

<p>Filepath: @ViewBag.FilePath</p>
```

This would print something along the lines of `C:\MySite\wwwroot\Content\images\svg-defs.svg`

Answer (score 6):

In .net Core you can get the root path with IHostingEnvironment service. 
You can use the HttpContext to get this service in views.

```
@{
    var service = Context.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment)) as Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment;
}

<span>Environment: @service.EnvironmentName</span>
<span>WebRootPath: @service.WebRootPath</span>
```